# How does one check if user has created a node of a content type in rules?

Tags: 7, nodes, rules

I would like to check if a user already authored a node from a content type before creating one for the user in rules. How do I create a condition for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to create a user flag (global flag type) then create a rule that flags the author of the node after creation. The rules condition also checks for the node's taxonomy term.

In my original rule, I added a new condition to check if user has NOT been flagged, then create the node for them.

On my website users won't be creating Group nodes themselves so this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

After seeing these big answers for Rules, I think you can try to do the same via code. Its much smaller and extremely faster than Rules!

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_prepare()
 * @param type $node 
 */
function mymodule_node_prepare($node) {
  if ($node->type == "my_type") {
    if (!isset($node->nid)) {
      $existing_nid = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE (type = :type1) AND uid = :uid", array("type1" => "my_type, "uid" => $node->uid))->fetchField();
      if ($existing_nid != FALSE) {
        drupal_goto("node/$existing_nid/edit");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This code checks if the user already have created a node, if yes, instead of allowing him to create a new one, we redirect him to the edit form of the existing node.

If you want this feature without Rules or code, you can try the Profile module. It has this magical feature to configure any content-type as 'profile'. And when a content-type is configure as 'profile', users are not allowed to have more than one node of that particular type.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: This will still let them reach the actual create a node etc. So this is more of a "reactive" solution than proactive solution. To stop them before they even start creating the node, I dont think rules is the tool for the job. You will most likely need to create a simple custom module with [form alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and a query. If the query returns > 1 show the form, if not show a message.

A very quick and easy way to do the checking part is using [VBO](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations).

- You create a VBO view with the UID (Author) as contextual filter and the content type as normal hidden filter. This will basically return any nids for the UID you give to the view.
- Set the pager to display a specified number = 1.
- Now, in rules you can use this VBO view as a condition "Check number of results returned by a VBO view"
- Choose the VBO view you created from the dropdown
- Use the data selector and the UID of the created/about to be created node for the arguments.
- Put 1 as the number of results and use negate checkbox.

This will basically return TRUE if the user HAS NOT already created a node of that content type (because of the negate checkbox). So what you will want to do is then in the actions delete the node (delete entity) and show a message using "Show a message" action.

Done.

Answer (score 1):

took me some time..

### First things first

I cant tell what action you want to trigger in rules, preventing the node from being saved [is not possible at this point anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428559/drupal-prevent-content-creation-edition-with-rules) (ran into this as I was testing my rule).

however, if you want to do something else, like editing the content, flag it for moderation or whatever I have a solution for you.

### Create a custom module with the new condition

This will create 2 new conditions, one for checking if a user created a post of a given node before, and one for simple text checking the content type and user entity. Both rules also check for the status of the post and return true only if published. This could easily be extended to check string content type and int uid.

module functions:

```
/*
 * Implementation of hook_rules_condition_info()
 */
function mymodule_rules_condition_info() {  
  return array(
    'mymodule_condition_has_other_post' => array(
      'label' => t('User has other post of same content type for given node.'),
      'parameter' => array(
        'node' => array('type' => 'node', 'label' => t('node')),
        'user' => array('type' => 'user', 'label' => t('user')),
      ),
      'group' => t('User'),
    ),
    'mymodule_condition_has_post' => array(
      'label' => t('User has post of content type.'),
      'parameter' => array(
        'contentType' => array('label' => t('content type'), 'type' => 'text'),
        'user' => array('type' => 'user', 'label' => t('user')),
      ),
      'group' => t('User'),
    ),
  );
}

function mymodule_condition_has_post($contentType, $user) {
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', $contentType)
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    ->propertyCondition('uid', $user->uid);
  $result = $query->execute();

  if (isset($result['node'])) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function mymodule_condition_has_other_post($node, $user) {
  return mymodule_condition_has_post($node->type, $user);
}
```

### Create a rule with your events, conditions and actions

I created one to send an email to all users with administrator role.

```
{ "rules_has_post" : {
    "LABEL" : "has_post",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "mymodule", "rules" ],
    "ON" : [ "node_presave" ],
    "IF" : [
      { "mymodule_condition_has_other_post" : { "node" : [ "node" ], "user" : [ "node:author" ] } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "mail_to_users_of_role" : {
          "roles" : { "value" : { "3" : "3" } },
          "subject" : "new node on [site:name]",
          "message" : "user [node:author] created a new node: [node:url]",
          "from" : "system@example.tld"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The [documentation pages](http://drupal.org/node/156754) are pretty outdated, it has a completly different syntax for d7 than to d6. I looked the correct one up in the `rules.api.php`.

Comment: Thanks! This will def come in handy when I'm dealing with a node type that users will be creating themselves.

Answer (score 0):

i found this piece of code on drupal.org that works pretty well

https://www.drupal.org/node/2052241

```
global $user;

$result = db_query("SELECT COUNT(nid) FROM node JOIN users ON node.uid = users.uid 

WHERE node.status = :status AND users.uid = :uid AND node.type = :type", 

array(":status"=> 1,":uid" => $user->uid, ":type" => 'configuration_1'))

->fetchField();

if ($result >= 1){
    return FALSE;
    }

 else{

return TRUE;

}
```

What i would love is checking if the user has any node created by a specific date eg tuesday